# What to do about fluid-simulation and smoke-simulation, fire tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since 2.82 some of the physics systems have undergone some major changes, specifically Fluid (when mantaflow was added). As such, for the site it seems to creates a bit of a mess with some tags because they overlap.

[fluid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-simulation)excerpt as of this writing:

> Questions about the Fluid simulation systems in blender. Blender has
> two systems for simulating liquids, a SPH (Smoothed Particle Dynamics)
> system integrated with the particle system, and a Lattice Boltzmann
> method which can be used create a variety of simulations.

[smoke-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoke-simulation) is actually an old wiki link as of writing this question, which is how this question came up in the first place.

[fire](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire)   no tag wiki

For a user that *reads* the tag wiki, this would be misleading, so the information should probably be updated.

Per [current documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/introduction.html#introduction), *fluid simulation* includes smoke/ fire and liquid, so wouldn't be surprised if users unknowingly begin to misuse [fluid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-simulation) for both causing future disorganization of questions as time goes on.

Examples of questions that was asked are [Both my fire emitter and my domain became 'wireframe', can't see them in render view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200329/both-my-fire-emitter-and-my-domain-became-wireframe-cant-see-them-in-render)

The OP is asking about fire, but tagged the question [fluid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-simulation) as well as [fire](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire)

also,

[Cold smoke simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199481/cold-smoke-simulation)

The OP is asking about smoke but has tagged the question [fluid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-simulation) and [smoke-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoke-simulation)

Finally, these two tag search results [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoke-simulation+fluid-simulation) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire+fluid-simulation) show that it is already becoming quite disorganized.

---

**The question**
How should these tags be organized? The given information needs to be updated. So while at it, is it a good idea to create a new tag, [liquid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liquid-simulation)  and use that for questions specifically about liquid, and use [smoke-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoke-simulation) for specific smoke questions, and then use [fluid-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-simulation) or create [mantaflow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mantaflow) for both of these?

Comment: Perhaps we could include a notice that the old tags are now deprecated and reference which new tag should be used instead. I'm not sure how often questions about mantaflow are asked, it may make sense to have specific tags for simulation types for mantaflow (e.g. mantaflow-fluid, mantaflow-fire, mantaflow-smoke)

Comment: @RobertGützkow perhaps, at a glance it seems that [tag:smoke-simulation] has had 15 questions this month, [tag:fluid-simulation] 31, and [tag:fire] has had 7. At the same time, I know there are users that still use old versions because of their hardware, so still may run into questions for now...

Comment: I think [tag:fluid-simulation] and [tag:smoke-simulation] should be kept system agnostic as tags respectively pertaining to fluid and smoke, regardless of the underlying system.

The fact that it now uses Mantaflow library or that both use the same system under the hood seems irrelevant and should probably not be reflected in our tags.

Having additional liquid-simulation or mantaflow tags will probably only add to the confusion. Incorrectly tagged questions should be fixed of course.